# Send background geolocation data to server

Tags: typescript, ionic3

I am sending the data from background geolocation in Ionic 3 to the server, as I am using rest API for this and in my case API isn't sending data to the server.

Here is my code:

```
this.userData = this.navParams.get('data');
        let clientId = this.userData.clientId;
        let role = this.userData.role;
        const config: BackgroundGeolocationConfig = {
            desiredAccuracy: 10,
            stationaryRadius: 20,
            distanceFilter: 1,
            debug: true, //  enable this hear sounds for background-geolocation life-cycle.
            stopOnTerminate: false, // enable this to clear background location settings when the app terminates
            notificationTitle: 'Nearby people check',
            notificationText: 'Share your location',
            interval: 500,
        }; 
        this.backgroundGeolocation.configure(config)
        .subscribe((location) => { 
            let longitude = location.longitude;
            let latitude = location.latitude;
            this.apiProvider.location(clientId, role, longitude, latitude).then(data=>{
                let apiData: any;
                apiData = data
                alert(apiData.code);
            });
        }); 
        this.backgroundGeolocation.start();
```

I want to send longitude and latitude to the server.

Comment: What is your question? Your code already seems to send location data somewhere...

Comment: found the error, have to use NgZone for that, as for backgroundGeolocation NgZone should be used to send data to api.